# How to preg_match first occurrence in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract `From:address` from an email body. Here is what I have so far:

```
$string = "From: user1@somewhere.com This is just a test.. the original message was sent From: user2@abc.com";

$regExp = "/(From:)(.*)/";
$outputArray = array();
if ( preg_match($regExp, $string, $outputArray) ) {
print "$outputArray[2]";
}
```

I would like to get the email address of the first occurrence of `From: ..` any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is too greedy: `.*` matches *any 0 or more characters other than a newline, as many as possible*. Also, there is no point in using capturing groups around literal values, it creates an unnecessary overhead.

Use the following regular expression:

```
^From:\s*(\S+)
```

The `^` makes sure we start searching from the beginning of the string,`From:` matches the sequence of characters literally, `\s*` matches optional spaces, `(\S+)` captures 1 or more non-whitespace symbols.

See [sample code](https://ideone.com/jCKHMu):

```
<?php
$string = "From: user1@somewhere.com This is just a test.. the original message was sent From: user2@abc.com";

$regExp = "/^From:\s*(\S+)/";
$outputArray = array();
if ( preg_match($regExp, $string, $outputArray) ) {
print_r($outputArray[1]);
}
```

The value you are looking for is inside `$outputArray[1]`.